# How does Spring works out the data type

Tags: java, spring, flux

all.
I am working with existing Spring Boot Flux REST end point and here is a Signature
..

```
Interface define REST end point  
@RequestMapping(
      method = RequestMethod.POST,
      value = "/api/{fileName}",
       @RequestMapping(
      method = RequestMethod.POST,
      value = "/{fileName}",
      consumes = { "application/octet-stream" }
  )
  default Mono<ResponseEntity<MyDTO>> postRequest(
      true,
      @Parameter(name = "fileName", description = "File name.", required = true, in = ParameterIn.PATH) @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName,
      @Parameter(name = "body", description = "vv") @Valid @RequestBody Mono<org.springframework.core.io.Resource> body,
      @Parameter(hidden = true) final ServerWebExchange exchange
  ),
      consumes = { "application/octet-stream" }
  )
//Java implementing the interface    
public Mono<ResponseEntity<MyDTO>> postMyRequest(
     
       Mono<org.springframework.core.ioResource> body,
      ServerWebExchange exchange
  ) {}
```

Now at the run time I am observing that body is of a type:
Mono.Peek

I would like to understand how did Spring worked it out ?
I call the service using postman:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/api/myfile.xml' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
--data-binary '@/C:/myfile.xml'
```